# Check if string contact value from array

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have two arrays like this:

```
var code = ["MDLS", "MS03", "MS04", "MDLX", "MDL3", "MDLY"]
var text = ["Tesla Model S", "Tesla Model S", "Tesla Model S", "Tesla Model X", "Tesla Model 3", "Tesla Model Y"]
var myString = String()
```

Normally I do this to check if a it contains what I am looking for:

```
if let value = data[indexPath.row].optionCodes?.contains("MDL3") {
    if value == true {
        print("Yes, optionCodes contains MDL3")
        myString = "Tesla Model 3"
    } else {
        print("No")
    }
}

if let value = data[indexPath.row].optionCodes?.contains("MS03") {
    if value == true {
        print("Yes, optionCodes contains MS03")
        myString = "Tesla Model S"
    } else {
        print("No")
    }
}

... and so on
```

In stead of wring a whole bunch of if let checks, how can I do all of these in one?

Comment: Why not just put it inside a function and reuse that?

Comment: Make it a dictionary pairing codes with texts and fetch by key? —  But even if you don't do that, saying `let value = data[indexPath.row].optionCodes` multiple times is ridiculous.

Comment: @aheze What do you mean? Like how exactly?

Answer (score 1):

I would make a dictionary.

```
let code = ["MDLS", "MS03", "MS04", "MDLX", "MDL3", "MDLY"]
let text = ["Tesla Model S", "Tesla Model S", "Tesla Model S", "Tesla Model X", "Tesla Model 3", "Tesla Model Y"]
let d = Dictionary(uniqueKeysWithValues: zip(code,text))
```

After that, it's basically a one-liner: just look up your code in the dictionary:

```
let testtext = "MDL3"
if let result = d[testtext] {
    print("got it!", result)
}
```

You can do your `contains` thing by looping thru `d.keys`.

Comment: I was mistaken. The `code` variable is not an array, but the codes are stored all as a string, like this: `MDLS,MS03,MS04,MDLX,MDL3,MDLY`. Will is not be possible to accomplish what I am trying to do because of this?

Comment: Convert in to an array then : var arr = "MDLS,MS03,MS04,MDLX,MDL3,MDLY".components(separatedBy: ",")

Comment: I literally answered the question you asked. I'm done.

Comment: @Westuo Please update the question if its not an array. So I can add answer based on that.